# VBA: Finding first empty cell in a selection of ranges

Tags: excel, vba, range

So i'm stuck again with my limited knowledge of VBA script.

I have this script:

```
Sub new_Group()
Dim rnTarget As Range
Set rnTarget = Blad2.Cells(Range("A9:A44").Cells.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
If rnTarget <> "" Then Set rnTarget = rnTarget.Offset(1)
Blad1.Range("A7:F15").Copy
Blad2.Range(rnTarget.Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Blad2.Range(rnTarget.Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Blad2.Range("P8").Value = Blad2.Range("P8").Value + 10

End Sub
```

It finds the first empty cell in the range of A9 to A44 and copys a premade number of cells in its place.

My question now is if it's possible to have it start looking in another range if no cell is empty in A9:A44? 
I want it to first check from A9 to A44 for empty cells, if none is found then start looking in range H9 to H44 and so on.

I have tried:

```
Set rnTarget = Blad2.Cells(Range("A9:A44, H9:H44").Cells.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
```

But then it just kept going down the A column. 
Do i have to make an Else in some way?

Comment: Small point: `Blad2.Range(rnTarget.Address).PasteSpecial` can be written as `rnTarget.PasteSpecial`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub new_Group()
    If (new_asd("A") = True) Then
        new_asd ("H")
    End If
End Sub

Function new_asd(new_col As String) As Boolean
    Dim rnTarget As Range

    new_asd = False

    If Blad2.Range(new_col & "44") = "" Then
        Set rnTarget = Blad2.Cells(Range(new_col & "9:" & new_col & "44").Cells.Count, Range(new_col & 1).Column).End(xlUp)
        If rnTarget <> "" Then
            Set rnTarget = rnTarget.Offset(1)
            Blad1.Range("A7:F15").Copy
            Blad2.Range(rnTarget.Address).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Blad2.Range("P8").Value = Blad2.Range("P8").Value + 10
        Else
            new_asd = True
        End If
    Else
        new_asd = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But there are some problems: 1, it now copies doubles. 2, it does not consider A9 as start instead it pastes into the topmost cell in A. 3, it still does not copies to H column after A9:A44 is filled.